# Python STFT for FFT with defined BL, window and overlap

Tags: python, fft

I'm encountering difficulties with the Short-Time Fourier Transform (STFT) in Python.

My goal is to implement a FFT with specified block length, window function, and overlapping. I aim to obtain an array that contains each FFT segment as complex data. To achieve this, I've been using the scipy STFT function, but I'm finding the output results to be confusing and unclear to me.

Especially the last axis of the output Zxx

In the manual:
Zxx ndarray
STFT of x. By default, **the last axis of Zxx corresponds to the segment times**

Ultimately, my objective is to generate a matrix containing complex spectra that can be further processed, such as averaging using root mean square (RMS) for analysis.

As a simple example, I've generated the following sine wave:

```
f = 10  # Frequency of the sinusoid
fs = 1000  # Sampling Frequency
dt = 1 / fs
T = 10  # Observation time in seconds
t = np.arange(0, T, dt)
x = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * t)
N = len(t)

f = np.fft.fftfreq(N, dt)
x_fft = np.fft.fft(x)
```

I understand that x_fft is an array with a shape of (10000,), which makes sense because I'm performing the FFT over the entire signal length. Now, I'm going to implement the STFT as follows:

```
nps = N
overlap = 0*nps
win = signal.get_window('hann', nps)

f_ft, t_ft, S_ft = signal.stft(
    x, fs=fs, nperseg=nps, noverlap=overlap, 
    return_onesided=False, axis=-1, scaling='spectrum')
```

It is evident that with the specified parameters, this STFT essentially functions as a Fast Fourier FFT over the entire length of the signal. However, I have observed that the shape of my data is (10000, 2) in one case and (5000, 3) when the parameter nps is set to N//2.

I have a few questions regarding this:

- Why do I have two (or three) axes, and what represents the last axis?
- How can I extract the accurate amplitude spectrum from this data, specifically for a frequency at 10 Hz with an amplitude of 1?
- What is the procedure for averaging the data with consideration for the last axis?

I appreciate your assistance in advance.

Best regards,
Jonas